# Does the Riemann hypothesis predict a bound for this prime-counting function?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers, asymptotics, riemann-hypothesis

Does the Riemann hypothesis predict an upper bound for

$$\left|f(x)-\left(\operatorname{li}(x)-\frac{x}{\log x} \right)\right|,\quad x\ge 2\tag{1}$$

where

$$f(x)=\sum\limits_{n=2}^x \frac{\Lambda(n)}{\log^2(n)}\tag{2}$$

and $\Lambda(n)$ is the [von Mangoldt function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Mangoldt_function)?

Comment: If you like my answer, please accept it officially (so that it turns green). Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Riemann hypothesis is *equivalent* to the following statement:
$$f(x)=\mathrm{li(x)}-\frac{x}{\log x}+O(\sqrt{x}),\qquad x\geq 2.$$
Note that
$$\mathrm{li(x)}=\mathrm{li(2)}+\frac{x}{\log x}-\frac{2}{\log 2}+\int_2^x\frac{dt}{\log^2 t},$$
hence the claim is that the Riemann hypothesis is equivalent to
$$f(x)=\int_2^x\frac{dt}{\log^2 t}+O(\sqrt{x}),\qquad x\geq 2.\tag{$\ast$}$$

**1.** The Riemann hypothesis implies $(\ast)$ as follows:
\begin{align*}
f(x)&=\int_{2-}^x\frac{d\psi(t)}{\log^2 t}\\
&=\int_2^x\frac{dt}{\log^2 t}+\int_{2-}^x\frac{d(\psi(t)-t)}{\log^2 t}\\
&=\int_2^x\frac{dt}{\log^2 t}+\left[\frac{\psi(t)-t}{\log^2 t}\right]_{2-}^x+2\int_2^x\frac{\psi(t)-t}{t\log^3 t}\,dt.
\end{align*}
Here $\psi(t)-t=O(\sqrt{t}\log^2 t)$ by the Riemann hypothesis, hence we conclude $(\ast)$.

**2.** Let us denote by $g(x)$ the integral in $(\ast)$. Then $(\ast)$ implies RH as follows:
\begin{align*}
\psi(x)&=\int_{2-}^x(\log^2 t)\,df(t)\\
&=\int_2^x(\log^2 t)\,dg(t)+\int_{2-}^x(\log^2 t)\,d(f(t)-g(t))\\
&=x-2+\left[(\log^2 t)\,(f(t)-g(t))\right]_{2-}^x-2\int_2^x\frac{\log t}{t}(f(t)-g(t))\,dt.
\end{align*}
Here $f(t)-g(t)=O(\sqrt{t})$ by $(\ast)$, hence we infer that $\psi(x)=x+O(\sqrt{x}\log^2 x)$, which is a form of the Riemann hypothesis.

Comment: I thought the error bound would perhaps be smaller than $O(\sqrt{x})$. For example $\left|f(x)-\left(\text{li}(x)-\frac{x}{\log x}+2.5\right)\right|<1$ for $x\in\mathbb{Z}\land 2\le x<19371$.

Comment: @StevenClark For every $x_0$ there is $x>x_0$ satisfying $\left|f(x)-\left(\mathrm{li}(x)-\frac{x}{\log x}\right)\right|>\sqrt{x}/\log^2 x$. This is because $|\psi(x)-x|=\Omega(x^{1/2}\log\log\log x)$ by Theorem 15.11 in Montgomery-Vaughan: Multiplicative number theory I. Probably one needs very large values of $x$ to obtain instances $\left|f(x)-\left(\mathrm{li}(x)-\frac{x}{\log x}\right)\right|>\sqrt{x}/\log^2 x$, and I suspect that values around $e^{1000}$ should exist in abundance. Compare with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skewes%27s_number